# Pivot List of entities using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, pivot

What I have is a list of entities coming back from a database that I want to pivot so that I end up with a new list of entities with the duplicates removed and the pivoted items attached to the new entity.

Currently I have a simple solution like this:

```
        IQueryable<Entity> results // being passed in from calling method.

        List<Entity> pivotedEntities = new List<Entity>();

        foreach (Entity entity in results)
        {
            if (pivotedEntities.Contains(entity))
            {
                Entity matchedEntity = pivotedEntities.Find(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
                matchedEntity.RelatedEntities.Add(entity.RelatedEntity);
            }
            else
            {
                pivotedEntities.Add(new Entity());
            }
        }

        return pivotedEntities.AsQueryable();
```

This works fine however I want to be able to achieve the same thing with a LINQ query on the IQueryable results variable so that it maintains its deffered execution rather than executing as soon as I enter the foreach.

I have other methods that get called around this code that also alter the IQueryable and I then want to execute the call to the database once all filters have been applied.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: For me your foreach looks good ... the only place i feel there is twice redundancy is pivotedEntities.Contains(entity) and pivotedEntities.Find(e => e.Id == entity.Id) ... reduce that to one...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will reduce few loops.

```
 List<Entity> pivotedEntities = new List<Entity>();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (Entity entity in results)
        {
            index = pivotedEntities.IndexOf(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
            if (index>-1)
            {
                pivotedEntities[index].RelatedEntities.Add(entity.RelatedEntity);
            }
            else
            {
                pivotedEntities.Add(new Entity());
            }
        }

        return pivotedEntities.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: The loops are not the problem here, the problem comes from the data retrieving cause by the foreach. The OP wants a deferred execution solution. If it is not possible, you should explain why.

Comment: Yes Cedric is right I need a deferred execution solution which effectively means completely getting rid of the foreach I think.

Comment: oh ok ... sorry I thought even refactoring was a part .. my bad... for the deferred execution ... I think in your case ,the 2 entities are same when they have same properties.I am assuming the 2 entities won't be exact duplicates(deep clones). In this scenario , you would need to do immediate execution. Sorry for the confusion.